# volatile keyword doesnt synchronize the values

Tags: multithreading, synchronized, volatile

Below piece of code gives me result as follows:

```
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Incrementing MY_INT to:1
Incrementing MY_INT to:2
Got Change for MY_INT :1loc:0
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Change listener
Incrementing MY_INT to:3
Change listener
Incrementing MY_INT to:4
Incrementing MY_INT to:5
Got Change for MY_INT :3loc:2
Change listener
```

Here my question is, since i used volatile, MY_INT value should be reflect as either 4 or 5. Why it is not reflecting. Soemtimes, even for that value we are getting 1.  Please someone let me know where i am going wrong.

```
public class VolatileTest {
    private static volatile int MY_INT = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChangeListener().start();
        new ChangeMaker().start();
    }

    static class ChangeListener extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int local_value = MY_INT;
            while ( local_value < 5){
                if( local_value!= MY_INT){
                   System.out.println("Got Change for MY_INT :"+ MY_INT+"loc:"+local_value);
                     local_value= MY_INT;
                }
 System.out.println("Change listener");
            }
        }
    }

    static class ChangeMaker extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int local_value = MY_INT;
            while (MY_INT <5){
                 System.out.println("Incrementing MY_INT to:"+(local_value+1));
                MY_INT = ++local_value;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'volatile keyword doesnt synchronize the values' - yes, and also, it does not somehow force your two threads to issue output in any guaranteed order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing that can happen:

```
 ChangeMaker                     ChangeListener
  ...                             ...
  MY_INT = 3
                                 Sees MY_INT != 2, calls println(...)
  MY_INT = 4
  MY_INT = 5
                                 local_value = MY_INT;    // 5
  all done (MY_INT==5)           all done (MY_INT==5)
```

The change listener can miss seeing changes because the test `local_value!=MY_INT` is not atomic with the assignment `local_value=MY_INT;`

Answer (score 0):

You did alright except one thing, you did not add synchronisation while accessing you volatile variable. Unlike atomics volatile variables guarantee you getting actual value but not changing. I guess it's better to use atomics as `AtomicInteger` in your case. Also you can change your `int` to `Integer` add extra `synchronized`to your code as at example below.

```
public class VolatileTest {
private static volatile Integer MY_INT = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChangeListener().start();
    new ChangeMaker().start();
}

static class ChangeListener extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int local_value = MY_INT;
        while (local_value < 5) {
            // ! Here
            synchronized (MY_INT) {
                if (local_value != MY_INT) {
                    System.out.println("Got Change for MY_INT :" + MY_INT + "loc:" + local_value);
                    local_value = MY_INT;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Change listener");
        }
    }
}

static class ChangeMaker extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        int local_value = MY_INT;
        while (MY_INT < 5) {
            System.out.println("Incrementing MY_INT to:" + (local_value + 1));
            // ! And here
            synchronized (MY_INT) {
                MY_INT = ++local_value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}